# How to toggle on/off a chart series using the Shinobi iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, charts, shinobi

My chart is composed of multiple chart series. I have created a custom legend with buttons so the user can press a button and show or hide a chart series as desired.  I have implemented a solution where the number of series are redefined after each button press but this requires a call to `reloadData` which is an expensive operation.

How do I hide a chart series without calling `reloadData`?  I am looking for a solution that only requires the chart to be redrawn using `redrawChart`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SChartSeries` objects (from which all series types inherit) have a `hidden` property. You can set this property to `NO` or `YES` to show or hide the series. You must call `redrawChart` after changing the value.

For example, the following method toggles the visibility of the first series in a chart:

```
- (IBAction)handleTogglePressed:(id)sender {
    SChartSeries *series = _chart.series[0];
    series.hidden = !series.hidden;
    [_chart redrawChart];
}
```

Comment: What about tooltip/crosshair? Of course you are able to make series.crosshairEnabled = NO at the same time when hiding the series but how to dispose a tooltip that already is rendered?

Comment: This does hide the series, but there's a goofy animation that occurs where the line flattens out and then slides off screen to the left. Any way to disable or modify this animation? Like have it fade out instead.